# Modules not found in opencart extensions

Tags: opencart

I downloaded opencart and without any changes to the default store I started it. The home page shows featured products but I want to change those products. I searched online but there is no modules options under extensions where I can change the products neither I could find it anywhere else. I am using the version 2.3.2. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

They migrated modules into extension types and mentioned inside the dropdown. Like below,

[image]